# Batch one liner append second command after powershell call

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, cmd, append

I have a batch file structured like below:

```
cd "C:\my\scripts\directory
powershell -f myPowershellSCript.ps1
exit %errorlevel%
```

This batch file is being sent through an in house remote shell application (which is mostly a black box to me) in a non-interactive way to another machine to be run.  I can execute the application and watch it's output on the terminal locally. The script is completing the powershell script and then just dropping back to the remote shell on the test machine without ever running the last line in the batch file.  I see the cmd.exe shell drop back to a prompt at C:\my\scripts\directory on the remote machine and just wait. Because it's non-interactive the script never completes.

I'd like to tag that last exit line onto the end of the line that calls powershell, but everything I've tried (below) has not worked.  I fear that powershell is taking everything as input instead of batch interpreting them as two separate commands.

```
powershell -f SecurePaymentsTestLauncher.ps1 && exit 1
powershell -nonInteractive -f SecurePaymentsTestLauncher.ps1 && exit 1
powershell -nonInteractive -command "& 'SecurePaymentsTestLauncher.ps1'" && exit 1
powershell -nonInteractive -command "& 'SecurePaymentsTestLauncher.ps1'" ; exit 1
powershell -nonInteractive -f SecurePaymentsTestLauncher.ps1 ; exit 1
```

still produces the same result.  No return from the remote execution.

**How do I append a second command to a batch file line when the first command is a call to powershell?**

Comment: It works in plain `cmd.exe`, so perhaps the issue is in your `black box` shell app. You could try to set exit code directly from your PS script using `Exit 1` (or any other code).

Comment: @beatcracker what works in plain cmd.exe, my script or appending the second command to the same line as powershell?  I'm already calling exit from the powershell script, that just drops back to the cmd.exe shell running on the remote machine.  The `blackbox` starts a cmd.exe that then calls then runs those commands?

Comment: Your original script. Maybe your `blackbox` starts `cmd` with `/K` argument, so it never exits?

Comment: @beatcracker interesting point, I know I can get at the source code so I'll see if I can investigate that, but given the nature of the underlying problem (this question was about a way to apply a temporary workaround (at least I hope it will work) so the underlying problem doesn't kill our automation while it's not fixed) I doubt it is the answer.   Given what I'm seeing so far I think there may not be a way to append that second command on the same line as the powershell command.

Comment: Maybe you could just kill parent cmd from your PS script, by adding this line to it: `Stop-Process -Force -Id (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Process -Filter "ProcessId='$PID'").ParentProcessId`. Or from batch like this: `powershell.exe -Command "$(& .\SecurePaymentsTestLauncher.ps1); Stop-Process -Force -Id (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Process -Filter "ProcessId=$PID").ParentProcessId"`

Comment: @beatcracker  That is definitely getting things to progress, thank you.  If you care to leave that as an answer I can accept it.  I assume there's no way to preserve and sort of exit code information with the force quit although, if there is a way that you know of to get it I would very much appreciate it.

Comment: @Tuffwer Is your PowerShell process exiting status 0?  The `&&` conditional operator only executes the command it precedes when the command it follows exits 0.  If you want to `exit 1` regardless of whether PowerShell exits zero or non-zero, use a single `&`.  You might also need to call the .ps1 script name as `.\SecurePaymentsTestLauncher.ps1`, and to add the `-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned` arguments.

Comment: [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/soever/returning-an-exit-code-from-a-powershell-script) might be helpful.

Comment: @rojo using a single & instead of two did the trick.  I know I've read that bit of information before about the dependency on the previous commands exit code for &&.  Not sure why I didn't catch that.  Thank you!  If you care to leave an answer with that info it is both the simplest and best behaved solution I've found so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your PowerShell process exiting status 0? The `&&` [conditional operator](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/condexec.php) only executes the command it precedes when the command it follows exits 0. If you want to `exit 1` regardless of whether PowerShell exits zero or non-zero, use a single `&`.

In your `powershell` command, you might also need to call the .ps1 script name as `.\SecurePaymentsTestLauncher.ps1` and add the `-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned` arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
cd "C:\my\scripts\directory"
start powershell -f myPowershellSCript.ps1
exit %errorlevel%
```

Using 'start' in front of powershell instantiates a separate powershell host outside of the batch script host, which will allow your ps1 file to do its thing while your batch script goes straight to 'exit %errorlevel%'

Comment: The `exit %errorlevel%` is supposed to be causing the cmd.exe shell on the remote machine to exit after powershell is finished, I need to wait for the powershell script to run. I did try this with a `start /wait` but then I lose the powershell output which I need.  I want to avoid having to dump the output to file and re-read it to print to the terminal at most (but not all) costs.

Comment: Are you just trying to run a script remotely on a machine? have you looked at Invoke-Command through WinRM and PSSessions? Sounds like you want psexec.exe functionality but without a secondary program.

Comment: I havn't looked at either of those.  This problem exists in an automation context within a larger framework. I've got some indicators of the underlying problem that I'm still chasing down, but really hoping to get work around hacked so the automation isn't completely broken while I fix the underlying problem.  The full structure here is 'Jenkisn -> blackbox -> cmd.exe -> powershell -> python script -> test.exe` where -> means calls. `test.exe` makes a system call out to plink (putty link). plink seems to be the ultimate culprit. If I replace plink with a sys call to cmd.exe it works fine. 1/?

Comment: I can reliably toggle the behavior by calling or not calling plink.  The python script is using a custom (read in house) pre-compiled ironpython environment to run, also part of the larger framework.  This framework manages all of our automation so it's not desirable to carve out a different path for this one test machine. 2/2